# Teradata - maximum load-factor

Tags: teradata

We run a Teradata datawarehouse and in order to operate fast & stable:
till which degree should/can we load it with data?

Obviously it should not be 100% full. But then: how much space should  be left 'unused'? Does this depend on the kind of operations we typically do (not many joins, mainly just filtering and i/o)?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It's usually somewhat between 70 and 80%, if you load more you might run into Spool Space problems & MiniCylPacks.

Comment: Thanks, is there any reference for this or is this just about experience?

Comment: There are some official numbers based on the type of your system (1xxx/2xxx/6xxx) and usage, your DBA should know about those specs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a guidance on that: [guide](http://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035-1094-160K/xxv1472240615038.html)

• Reserve 25% to 35% of total space for spool space

• Allow an extra 5% of PERM space in user DBC.